# Show CircularProgressIndicator in AppBar with same size and padding as an IconButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing a `CircularProgressIndicator` in `AppBar` while some task is completing. The problem is that `CircularProgressIndicator` is occupying the same height as the `AppBar`.

I tried wrapping `CircularProgressIndicator` with `Padding`. It doesn't seem to work.

How do I show `CircularProgressIndicator` in `AppBar` with the same size and padding as an `IconButton`?

Edit: Adding sample code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MyApp(),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isButtonPressed;
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _isButtonPressed = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
          actions: [
            _isButtonPressed
                ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Click me'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isButtonPressed = !_isButtonPressed;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `CircularProgressIndicator` with a `SizedBox` `Widget`:

```
Center(
   heightFactor: 1,
   widthFactor: 1,
   child:
      SizedBox(
       height: 24,
       width: 24,
       child: CircularProgressIndicator()
   )
)
```

This will force the `CircularProgressIndicator` to fit inside the `SizedBox`.

Follows a full code snippet for your scenario:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MyApp(),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isButtonPressed;
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _isButtonPressed = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
          actions: [
            _isButtonPressed
                ? Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: Center(
                      heightFactor: 1,
                      widthFactor: 1,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 24,
                        width: 24,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Click me'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isButtonPressed = !_isButtonPressed;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `CircularProgressIndicator` is still occupying the same height as `AppBar`. But I can control the width of `CircularProgressIndictor` with `SizedBox`.

Comment: Could you please share a minimal working version of your code so that I can troubleshoot your issue?

Comment: `Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric( vertical: 16, horizontal: 12),child: SizedBox( width: 24,child: CircularProgressIndicator( strokeWidth: 1.5 backgroundColor: Colors.white, ), ),)`     It seems to work but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check if it works as you expected

Comment: Can you tell why `SizedBox` couldn't reduce the height of `CircularProgressIndicator`?